# Header component shift left aligned text when adding right aligned text

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I have a header component (form ant design react) in which I have a left-aligned title and I added a right aligned text, some thing like "Welcome, ":

```
<Header style={{ padding: 10 }}>
      <Avatar style={{ float: "right" }} src='./dp.png' />
      <Text type='secondary' style={{ color: "white", float: "right" }}>
        {user ? user.attributes.email : ""}
      </Text>
      <Title style={{ color: "white" }} level={3}>
        MyWebAppName
      </Title>
    </Header>
```

The issue is that, without the right aligned text my header looks good:

```
<Header style={{ padding: 10 }}>
      <Avatar style={{ float: "right" }} src='./dp.png' />

      <Title style={{ color: "white" }} level={3}>
        MyWebAppName
      </Title>
    </Header>
```

[image: goodOne]

However, when I add right-aligned text the header shifts down the original title:

[image]

I believe it is a CSS issue rather than a bad use of ant design library, however, I don't know how to tackle it.

Answer (score 0):

add this`clear:both; display:table; content'';`to parent div in which child div are floating.